# Is there a collection of chess images in public domain?

Tags: history

I am looking for images of chess players, pieces, as well as any other graphics related to chess - public domain only.

Comment: Wikipedia tends to have lots of public domain pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creative Commons search might be a good place to start:

http://search.creativecommons.org/

It allows you search other sites such as Flickr and Google Images, while making sure you can legally use what you find.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/greatest-chess-photos

Has probably some of the most epic pictures in chess history